# Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

Reading the limited documentation that Google has provided, I get the feeling that it is possible to change the look (drawable) of a ProgressBar/ProgressDialog by simply creating a new style an assigning it to the style property of the ProgressBar. But I cannot get this to work properly. Here is what I did so far:

I created a shape like this (mp2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="ring"
  android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
  android:thicknessRatio="4"
  android:useLevel="false">
 <size android:width="50dip" android:height="50dip" />
 <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false" android:startColor="#300000ff" android:centerColor="#500000ff" android:endColor="#ff0000ff" />
</shape>
```

then created an animation (mp3.xml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="30" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="30" android:toDegrees="60" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="60" android:toDegrees="90" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="120" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="120" android:toDegrees="150" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="150" android:toDegrees="180" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="180" android:toDegrees="210" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="210" android:toDegrees="240" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="240" android:toDegrees="270" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="300" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="300" android:toDegrees="330" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
 <item android:duration="70">
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/mp2" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="330" android:toDegrees="360" android:repeatCount="1" />
 </item>
</animation-list>
```

then created a style (attrs.xml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar" name="customProgressBar">
  <item name="android:progressDrawable">@anim/mp3</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

and the in my main.xml I have set the style like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawingCacheQuality="high">
 <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/customProgressBar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But it still shows the same drawable as before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just happened to be browsing samples and came across yours after reading [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/51188f7e52a83ded/de8c88581592d059?lnk=raot). Hopefully it solves your problem.

Comment: I knew how to create shapes/gradiant/animation. The one I have created above is based on the posting you are refering to (I had to change it a bit becase it looks very choppy and slow). I was just hoping to be able to achive this using the "style".
Thanks for the reponce anyway

Answer (score 151):

I used the following for creating a custom progress bar.

File `res/drawable/progress_bar_states.xml` declares the colors of the different states:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#000001"
                    android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#0d1522"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#234"
                        android:centerColor="#234"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a24"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#144281"
                    android:centerColor="#0b1f3c"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#06101d"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the code inside your layout xml:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_states"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="8dip" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
    android:indeterminateOnly="false" 
    android:max="100">
</ProgressBar>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @YuliaRogovaya is it because the drawables aren't in clip elements?  I couldn't make it work either; suspect the clip element is the key.

Comment: how to do this for a `ProgressDialog` ?

Comment: @Nezam I can't give you exact code or samples but this is what you would need to do. Provide a custom theme to the ProgressDialog. The custom theme would define the progressbar style.

Comment: It would be nice to see a screenshot of this thing in action

Comment: @Jona I know its been awhile, but how could I make this drawable smaller in height??

Comment: can we define the max-width of the progress bar in this drawable?

Comment: in case it doesn't work for someone, make sure you are including `<clip>` tags. Just leaving it here.

Answer (score 56):

I was having some trouble using an Indeterminate Progress Dialog with the solution here, after some work and trial and error I got it to work.

First, create the animation you want to use for the Progress Dialog. In my case I used 5 images.

**../res/anim/progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation.xml:**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_4" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_5" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

**Where you want to show a ProgressDialog:**

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(Context.this);
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation));
dialog.setMessage("Some Text");
dialog.show();
```

This solution is really simple and worked for me, you could extend ProgressDialog and make it override the drawable internally, however, this was really too complicated for what I needed so I did not do it.

Comment: Thanks for noting "dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable()"

Comment: Is there a way to have just an image in the dialog, so no message, but a drawable in the entire dialog?

Comment: @Diego I haven't tried it, but I don't see why not. Have you tried using a drawable that would take up the space you wanted (i.e. had a long aspect ratio) and not setting any text to the Dialog?

Answer (score 45):

Try setting:

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
```

It worked for me. Here is also the code for progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="48dip" android:height="48dip" />

        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
            android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#ffffd300" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: If you want to use a drawable then just `android:drawable=` in the rotate tag and then remove the shape. Finally someone who answers the spinning progress bar question.

Comment: It sets color but progress bar is not rotating

Comment: To quickly adjust rotation speed `android:toDegrees` can be set to higher value. Setting it to `android:toDegrees="1080"` will increase rotation in 3 times.

Answer (score 10):

Your style should look like this:

```
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar" name="customProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@anim/mp3</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

i do your code .i can run but i need modify two places:

1. `name="android:indeterminateDrawable"` instead of `android:progressDrawable`
2. modify name attrs.xml ---> styles.xml

Comment: you modify your android:startColor="#300000ff“  to #FF00ff00,modify a other color

Answer (score 6):

Custom progress with scale!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:duration="150">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_no_smile_eyes_off"
            android:scaleGravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="150">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_no_smile_eyes_on"
            android:scaleGravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="150">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_smile_eyes_off"
            android:scaleGravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="150">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_smile_eyes_on"
            android:scaleGravity="center" />
    </item>

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomProgressBar {
    private RelativeLayout rl;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Context mContext;
    private String color__ = "#FF4081";
    private ViewGroup layout;
    public CustomProgressBar (Context context, boolean isMiddle, ViewGroup layout) {
        initProgressBar(context, isMiddle, layout);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar (Context context, boolean isMiddle) {
        try {
            layout = (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        initProgressBar(context, isMiddle, layout);
    }

    void initProgressBar(Context context, boolean isMiddle, ViewGroup layout) {
        mContext = context;
        if (layout != null) {
            int padding;
            if (isMiddle) {
                mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
                // mProgressBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pb_custom_progress);//Color.parseColor("#55000000")
                padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding);
            } else {
                padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding);
                mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
            }
            mProgressBar.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            mProgressBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pg_back);
            mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                try {
                    color__ = AppData.getTopColor(context);//UservaluesModel.getAppSettings().getSelectedColor();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    color__ = "#FF4081";
                }
                int color = Color.parseColor(color__);
//                color=getContrastColor(color);
//                color__ = color__.replaceAll("#", "");//R.color.colorAccent
                mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            } 
            }

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
            if (!isMiddle) {
                int valueInPixels = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding);
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) (valueInPixels / 1.5));//(int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(valueInPixels, context));
                rl.setClickable(false);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            } else {
                rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                rl.setClickable(true);
            }
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            mProgressBar.setScaleY(1.55f);
            mProgressBar.setScaleX(1.55f);
            mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(lp);

            rl.addView(mProgressBar);
            layout.addView(rl, params);
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        if (mProgressBar != null)
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide() {
        if (mProgressBar != null) {
            rl.setClickable(false);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

And then call

```
customProgressBar = new CustomProgressBar (Activity, true);
customProgressBar .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in this case you can still go with a complete customized AlertDialog by having a seperate layout file set in the alert dialog and set the animation for your imageview using part of your above code that should also do it!