# Styling progress dialog in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Spent half day to understand how to change some styles to progress dialog , but I am not able to do so.

Very simple thing I wanted to start with, change the spinner color in progress dialog to some other color other than white ! , Got stuck  here itself.

In Android SDK , they are using some image and applying animation to it , I will have to do everything from scratch to change the color of the spinner ?

Any good examples where progress dialog has been modified would be helpful , I have seen in documentation , google search results upto 4-6 pages :) ,
still not able to get it.

Any interesting way to show progress dialog other than default one ?

I would appreciate if someone can provide good blog on Applying themes and styles , which explains in detail.

Some code which I am using,

```
dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(this);      
dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

Trying to do lot with dialog1, but not getting any desired result.

Thank you

Comment: It seems like this thread could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog/4454450#4454450

Comment: @Drahakar - Will definitively try it, TY.

Comment: Hey did you find any answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

```
final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(
                            SearchScreen.this, "", progressbarSearching);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                    progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.anim.progressbar_handler));
```

**progressbar_handler.xml**

```
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

    <size android:width="48dip" android:height="48dip" />

    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
        android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#FF0000" />

</shape>
```