# How to change default ProgressDialog circle color in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using `ProgressDialog` for showing progressbar

```
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage(message);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();
```

And it is coming like this

[image]

I want to change the green color of the circle to red. is there any way?

I tried

```
.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908289/styling-progress-dialog-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Comment: May be a duplicate questions. Please check <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android">this</a>

Comment: @MohanRex the possible duplicate you have raised are wrong. Because those address questions about android.widget.ProgressBar and this question is about android.app.ProgressDialog. Both are totally different. So delete your wrong flags

Answer (score 62):

In style.xml create style for dialog box :

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/grey_dialog_box</item>
</style>
```

In this  `"android:textColorPrimary"` need to define color you want to show and in java code define style of `ProgressDialog` like :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

MORE : http://androidprogressdialogcustomcolor.blogspot.in/

Comment: This doesn't change round shape color

Comment: Also, "show" is static and does not work with a new instance of ProgressDialog.

Comment: <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>  this is key value to change loader spinner/circle color.

Comment: Still works on Kotlin. The key, as said before is 'colorAccent' in a new style.

Answer (score 31):

Add Style.xml

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

set style to progress dialog

```
pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
```

Comment: Best answer! Only one exactly doing what asker wanted.

Comment: Thanks this answer is easy and should be the right answer

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Create layout for progress dialog as named as custom_progress_dialog.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="56dip" android:height="56dip" />

        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="#1e9dff"
            android:angle="0"
             />

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

make sure that `indeterminate = true` and `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_background"`
 In the activity layout where you want to use the loader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_dialog"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not a perfect solution, but may help.

Also check my previous comment.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39687893/2598453

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_message));
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.setCancelable(false);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Drawable drawable = new ProgressBar(this).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate();
    drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
}

progress.show();
```

Answer (score 7):

Get the resource from the android resource that being used by the ProgressDialog.

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
progress.setTitle("Loading");
progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
progress.show();
ProgressBar progressbar=(ProgressBar)progress.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#C60000"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Example where setting color to red:

```
ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(
                context,
                null,
                android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);

spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your **Application Theme**, change **colorAccent**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Bash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">Add your color here</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/gray</item>
</style>
```

use whatever color you want

Answer (score 1):

The perfect and simple solution for custom color progress bar.
[image: Custom Progress bar]

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar{
    public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

and use it in your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.mayproject.views.CustomProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to define the colour ad-hoc, without needing inheritance or dedicated XML, you can use something like this:

```
/** Styles a ProgressDialog to use a themed Spinner. */
public void setStyledProgressDialog(final Context pContext, final ProgressDialog pProgressDialog, final int pColorResourceId) {
    // Allocate a new ProgressBar.
    final ProgressBar lProgressBar = new android.widget.ProgressBar(pContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
    // Configure the IndeterminateDrawable.
    lProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(pContext, pColorResourceId), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    // Assign the ProgressBar to the ProgressDialog.
    pProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(lProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use material dialogs library (https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#indeterminate-progress-dialogs) the simplest solution could be to use the progress dialog from that library. The circle will be automatically colored with the primary color:

```
MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                    .content(R.string.loading)
                    .progress(true, 0)
                    .show();
```