# How to set Default progress Dialog Spinner color by programatically in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change default progress dialog spinner color..but I went some tutorial but not usefull

```
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018157/how-to-change-default-progressdialog-circle-color-in-android

Comment: above link not helpful

Comment: what API are you using?

Comment: I am using api:21

Comment: @rakesh Try updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this but i doesn't had text like loading...

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, null);
        ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(MainActivity.this, null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#53CBF1"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(spinner);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

> change **colorAccent** in Your main theme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

> For all devices support below 21 you using code by custom layout to progress dialog...

**custom_progressdialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:padding="5dp"

>

    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**

```
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(demo.this);
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
    ProgressBar progressbar=(ProgressBar)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#C60000"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

In res Directory, Create 1 XML File and name it `progress.xml`, This is the code for the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#447a29" 
            android:endColor="#447a29"
            android:angle="0"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

**Step 2:**

Modify `android:startColor` and `android:endColor` as whatever Color you want.

**Step 3:**

set that progress.xml in ProgressBar's backgound .

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background ="@xml/progress">
```

Answer based on [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-change-color-in-circular-progress-bar), By Chirag Raval.