# Change color of Indeterminate in progress dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressdialog

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx,null,null);
                dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                dialog.setContentView(new ProgressBar(ctx));
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

I need to change color of loading circle

Comment: Try this once http://stackoverflow.com/a/39180185/3142611

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

and set to the dialog :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogStyle);
```