# How to make a custom progress bar in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need help in doing a custom progress bar.
I would like to change the stock android progress bar like this one:
http://i56.tinypic.com/dlgbae.jpg

To something like this or any other shape:

http://i52.tinypic.com/2r750dh.jpg

Can someone point me to the right direction, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load different `Drawable` for the progress bar

Simple way to do this is just using

`android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogbar_new_drawable"`

Either put PNG in `res/drawable` folder in your project or create your own xml with specify colors/gradients/shapes etc.

Comment: Thanks. But how will the image be formatted? Can you point me to some example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog See here this is with colors it can be adapted with custom pictures as well