# Is it possible to change the shape of progressbar android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Is it possible? Please throw some light in customizing the shape of the progress bar.Thanks
[image: Click here to see the expected shape]

Comment: Yes it's possible. You must customize it.

Comment: @Piyush I need to acheive a bone shaped progress bar . Please see the image link in the question.

Comment: I hope the answer for this question should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057023/how-to-make-a-custom-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible. you can make custom progressbar.
Use Google Progressbar instead. 
Visit: [Google Progress bar](https://github.com/jpardogo/GoogleProgressBar)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I need a bone shaped progress bar. Please see the image link .

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use a [`ClipDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) as progressDrawable to clip a custom progress image, combined with a custom background image behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need a bone shaped progress bar. Please see the image link

Comment: I've seen the image. You need to use bone-shaped images and clip the progress part on top of the border part.