# Android: How can make progress bar like this

Tags: android

I am working in android. i want to show a progress bar.

Progress is based on number of check in persons.

suppose, if number of **check in =6** then following should be displayed:-

[image]

if number of **checkin=10** then this following should be displayed:-

[image]

Please tell me how can i manage this RED COLOR BALLOON position according to progress bar position of progress.

you may provide some links for this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tell me how can i manage this RED COLOR BALLOON  position according to progress bar position of progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this progress bar::

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/

[Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)

Comment: How can this be the solution ? There is no mention of how to do the red balloon in any of this link.