# Android - Custom progress bar to show the currently playing second

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a custom progress bar with a different style. Hopefully, I found a good example how to achieve this in this thread: [Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog), and it's working fine.

However, I need also to display the played time in a simple view just above the progress bar. The tricky part is that this view should move along with the progress of the progressBar and display the minutes and seconds.
To fully understand me what am I talking about, just take a look at the Vimeo player: https://jira.sakaiproject.org/secure/attachment/25159/Vimeo+player+in+Sakai.jpg. (00:22).

Could you please give me some some directions from where to start, and how this effect can be achieved?

My first idea is to get the duration of the audio file (milliseconds), and then depending of the current position, convert the milliseconds to pixels and move the View horizontally with "X" pixels.... but maybe there's a more intelligent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but i saw your post today, and a bit later i found that [blog entry](http://www.jagsaund.com/blog/2011/11/6/customizing-your-progress-bar-part-one.html). I think part 2 is exactly what you are looking for.

Ok, it only shows the progress in the bubble above, but I think it will guide you to the right way