# How to display "loading" image near text view

Tags: android

I need a way to show "loading" image near text view. In my app, some data receives from server periodically and while these processes executing I need to show to user loading(wait) image like this image below.

[sample image http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1403/androidwait.png](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1403/androidwait.png)

Then, when executing finished, I want loading image to disappear from screen. Some time later when asyn task start to receive some data again. This image will show again. This all process will go periodically. I don't use ProgressDialog. Because it cover all screen and keep user waiting.

Important point: when image disappeared, its area in layout will used by text view and no blank will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.example.com/) is answer of my question. When we apply this xml code where we want to show rotating circle progress bar in layout,

```
<ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

it seems just I want.

And then using java code to start and stop it.

Comment: I'm interested by your tutorial but the url you gave `http://example.com` is wrong, do you still have it?

Comment: @jolivier, you right, url is broken. Sorry now i can't remember which was this tutorial is. If i find it's url again, i will update it.

Comment: no problem, I understood in the mean time that ProgressBar handles also the rotating circle despite its name. So i found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why not to use ProgressBar? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

You can inflate it anywhere inside your main UI and operate it with `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Please don't forget to do it ONLY in main UI thread.
So either use AsyncTask's onPostExecute, or wrap execution with `activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.

**Note:** ProgressBar in Android can have 2 states: either horizontal with progress, or just rotating circle, just like on your screenshot. Default is 2nd, so just what you want.

Good luck

Comment: I don't use ProgressBar, because there will be more than one wait image.

Comment: "rotating circle" solution can be use, I will think it.

Comment: Note, you can always provide any custom animated drawable to ProgressBar, so if you just don't like default "rotating circle" - check this thread for details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog

Answer (score 0):

You can place an imageview then in asyntask

onPreExecute(){//Imageview gets set visible here}

onPostExecute(){//Turn imageview off here}

Comment: You can set layout weight and layout width for textview and imageview in postExecute. So you can take advantage of that for dynamic layout resizing.