# Android：ProgressDialog,I setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable),but the drawable is not rotated(animated)

Tags: android, user-interface, progressdialog

I want to custom my `ProgressDialog`,I have made

`setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.processbar_style))`,

this is R.drawable.processbar_style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/processbar"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
 />
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304685/1143977

Comment: When I Using ProgressBar in a View,It can word very well. But,when I do the same things in ProgressDialog,the drawable is not rotated(animated). So I think it is can not be explained。

Comment: I have read the answer of url which you give me .I want by rotate to show my ProgressBar ，not by anmiated. because, I just a one .png, can you tell me a way to reach target, I thanks u very much.Ps.english is not my mother tongue， please forgive me so poor description。Thank u over and over。

Answer (score 0):

use it programatically like this:

define and start your progressdialog wherever you are starting your work for which you wanna show progress

```
    pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd=ProgressDialog.show(*Your_Activity*.this,"","Please wait");
```

and just end it when the work is completed.

```
    pd.dismiss();
```

it gives me animated progress display in a progress dialog box.