# Modify default progress of webview in android

Tags: android, webview

[image]

How to modify the progress bar of webview or how to create custom progress on top webview?

Comment: to modify progress use setProgress method.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog) out.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a custom progress bar, you'll need a Runnable thread and a message handler which will keep updating your progress bar.

Check the snippet below:-

Get your progress bar and then start the new **Thread**

```
myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
new Thread(myThread).start();
```

**New Thread**:-

```
private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {
while (myProgress<100){
try{
myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch(Throwable t){
}
}
}
}
```

The message sent from the try block above, will be handled in the **handleMessage** method of your **Handler** below:-

```
Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
myProgress++;
myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how would i get webview progress? , these things i can ?

Answer (score 0):

That was for custom progress bar. If you need to play around with the **Webview** then I think this should help you out.

A WebView has several customization points where you can add your own behavior. They are:

- Creating and setting a **WebChromeClient** subclass. This class is called
  when something that might impact a browser UI happens, for instance,
  progress updates and JavaScript alerts are sent here.
- Creating and setting a **WebViewClient** subclass. It will be called when
  things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors
  or form submissions. You can also intercept URL loading here(via
  **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**()).

  ```
  // To display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
  // browser app does.
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // javascript if needed.

  final Activity activity = this;
  webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
       // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
       activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
     }
   });

   webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
              Toast.makeText(activity, "Page Load Error! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   });

   webview.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
  ```

Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and this [too](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for more clarity.