# How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar in Android

Tags: android

i want to custom progress bar in circle shape like same as [download blazer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdjsoftware.download&feature=search_result) app in google play shop.i am expected like below screen shot:

[image]

any one help me how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog

Comment: I found this example very good.
http://mrigaen.blogspot.it/2013/12/create-circular-progress-bar-in-android.html

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a circular progressbar in Android which rotates on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The best two libraries I found on the net are on github:

- https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel
- https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c

Hope that will help you

Comment: The first one is exactly like Google's Play Music application is using. It is grand!

Comment: you can also try this one, very simple to use:
https://github.com/daentech/CircularDemo

Comment: This library https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c has problem so don't use this

Answer (score 32):

I've encountered same problem and not found any appropriate solution for my case, so I decided to go another way. I've created custom drawable class. Within this class I've created 2 Paints for progress line and background line (with some bigger stroke). First of all set startAngle and sweepAngle in constructor:

```
    mSweepAngle = 0;
    mStartAngle = 270;
```

Here is onDraw method of this class:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw background line
    canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 0, 360, false, mPaintBackground);
    // draw progress line
    canvas.drawArc(mRectF, mStartAngle, mSweepAngle, false, mPaintProgress);
}
```

So now all you need to do is set this drawable as a backgorund of the view, in background thread change sweepAngle:

```
mSweepAngle += 360 / totalTimerTime // this is mStep
```

and directly call InvalidateSelf() with some interval (e.g every 1 second or more often if you want smooth progress changes) on the view that have this drawable as a background. Thats it!

P.S. I know, I know...of course you want some more code. So here it is all flow:

1. Create XML view :

   ```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   ```
2. Create and configure Custom Drawable class (as I described above). Don't forget to setup Paints for lines. Here paint for progress line:

   ```
   mPaintProgress = new Paint();
   mPaintProgress.setAntiAlias(true);
   mPaintProgress.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
   mPaintProgress.setStrokeWidth(widthProgress);
   mPaintProgress.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
   mPaintProgress.setColor(colorThatYouWant);
   ```

Same for backgroung paint (set width little more if you want)

3. In drawable class create method for updating (Step calculation described above)

   ```
   public void update() {
       mSweepAngle += mStep;
       invalidateSelf();
   }
   ```
4. Set this drawable class to YourTimerView (I did it in runtime) - view with @+id/timer from xml above:

   `OurSuperDrawableClass superDrawable = new OurSuperDrawableClass();
    YourTimerView.setBackgroundDrawable(superDrawable);`
5. Create background thread with runnable and update view:

   ```
   YourTimerView.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // update progress view
           superDrawable.update();
       }
   });
   ```

Thats it ! Enjoy your cool progress bar. Here screenshot of result if you're too bored of this amount of text.[image]

Comment: I am currently using a while loop in an UIthread in the post. However it only updates once it is fully done. Anyone knows what might be going wrong?

Comment: @JordiSipkens you cannot use while loop in UIThread because you're blocking ui, perform operations in background thread and update view as frequent as you want. If you will be updating view every millisecond - animation will be smoother. You can make mProgress++ in background thread with Thread.sleep(1) and update view with mView.post();

Comment: Using this approach, how do i dynamically change color of the circular progress bar after some intervals? say for example 0-50 red color, 51-100 blue color? and the entire animation should be in one smooth animation?

Comment: @akash89 just change color of the paint to whatever you want, If you want color to change smoothly - you need to calculate it depending on current progress and interpolate across interval

Comment: @AlexPerevozchykov :: is there any reference code that I can check and reuse?

Comment: @akash89 use Paint.setColor(int your color) to change color and circle will be drawn with this color in next draw call. As for interpolation you can use for instance ArgbEvaluator.evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue)

Comment: can you please post your entire code (or a link to) so it's easier to understand ?

Comment: I have created a drawable class with the idea you have given. and set it as a background for a textview and an image view as well. But that circular progress bar is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why can't you just post the entire code? it just confuses people and not everyone can make it work.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Circle Android Custom Progress Bar]

[for more information on How to create Circle Android Custom Progress Bar view this link](http://mycodingworld1.blogspot.com/2015/02/crating-circle-android-custom-progress.html)

Step 01
You should create an xml file on drawable file for configure the appearance of progress bar . So Im creating my xml file as  circular_progress_bar.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="120"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="140">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
     android:angle="0"
     android:type="sweep"
    android:thicknessRatio="50.0">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>

 </item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
   <rotate
    android:fromDegrees="120"
    android:toDegrees="120">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
     android:angle="0"
     android:type="sweep"
    android:thicknessRatio="50.0">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
</rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Step 02
Then create progress bar on your xml file
Then give the name of xml file on your drawable folder as the parth of android:progressDrawable

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

Step 03
Visual the progress bar using thread

```
package com.example.progress;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private ProgressBar progBar;
  private TextView text;
     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     private int mProgressStatus=0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progBar= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    dosomething();
}



  public void dosomething() {

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        final int presentage=0;
            while (mProgressStatus < 63) {
                mProgressStatus += 1;
                // Update the progress bar
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                        text.setText(""+mProgressStatus+"%");

                    }
                });
                try {



                    Thread.sleep(50);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
  }


 }
```

Comment: Animation isn't that smooth, but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

A very useful [lib](https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar/blob/master/README.md) for custom progress bar in android.

In your layout file

```
<com.lylc.widget.circularprogressbar.example.CircularProgressBar
android:id="@+id/mycustom_progressbar"
.
.
.
 />
```

and Java file

```
CircularProgressBar progressBar = (CircularProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mycustom_progressbar);
progressBar.setTitle("Circular Progress Bar");
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this piece of code to create circular progress bar(pie chart). pass it integer value to draw how many percent of filling area. :)

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);
        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 
        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this cool custom progress bar by creating the custom view.  I have overriden the onDraw() method to draw the circles, filled arc and text on the canvas.

following is the custom progress bar

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.graphics.Path;

import android.graphics.Rect;

import android.graphics.RectF;

import android.os.Build;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.View;

import com.investorfinder.utils.UiUtils;


public class CustomProgressBar extends View {


private int max = 100;

private int progress;

private Path path = new Path();

int color = 0xff44C8E5;

private Paint paint;

private Paint mPaintProgress;

private RectF mRectF;

private Paint textPaint;

private String text = "0%";

private final Rect textBounds = new Rect();

private int centerY;

private int centerX;

private int swipeAndgle = 0;


public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initUI();
}

public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initUI();
}

public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initUI();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(UiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 1));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(color);


    mPaintProgress = new Paint();
    mPaintProgress.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaintProgress.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintProgress.setStrokeWidth(UiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 9));
    mPaintProgress.setColor(color);

    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setColor(color);
    textPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int radius = (Math.min(viewWidth, viewHeight) - UiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 2)) / 2;

    path.reset();

    centerX = viewWidth / 2;
    centerY = viewHeight / 2;
    path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, Path.Direction.CW);

    int smallCirclRadius = radius - UiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 7);
    path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, smallCirclRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
    smallCirclRadius += UiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 4);

    mRectF = new RectF(centerX - smallCirclRadius, centerY - smallCirclRadius, centerX + smallCirclRadius, centerY + smallCirclRadius);

    textPaint.setTextSize(radius * 0.5f);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawArc(mRectF, 270, swipeAndgle, false, mPaintProgress);

    drawTextCentred(canvas);

}

public void drawTextCentred(Canvas canvas) {

    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

    canvas.drawText(text, centerX - textBounds.exactCenterX(), centerY - textBounds.exactCenterY(), textPaint);
}

public void setMax(int max) {
    this.max = max;
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    this.progress = progress;

    int percentage = progress * 100 / max;

    swipeAndgle = percentage * 360 / 100;

    text = percentage + "%";

    invalidate();
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

In layout XML

```
<com.your.package.name.CustomProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
```

in activity

```
CustomProgressBar progressBar = (CustomProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    progressBar.setMax(9);

    progressBar.setProgress(5);
```

Comment: Just add this line in above class and you will be good to go: mPaintProgress.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

Comment: Using this approach, how do i dynamically change color of the circular progress bar after some intervals? say for example 0-50 red color, 51-100 blue color? and the entire animation should be in one smooth animation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a new view class and derive from the existing ProgressBar.  Then override the onDraw function.  You're going to need to make direct draw calls to the canvas for this, since its so custom-  a combination of drawText, drawArc, and drawOval should do it-  an oval for the outer ring and empty portions, and an arc for the colored in parts.  You may end up needing to override onMeasure and onLayout as well.  Then in your xml, reference this view by class name like this  when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple class which u can use to make custom ProgressBar dialog.
Actually it has 2 default layouts:
- First dialog with no panel with progress bar and animated text centered over it
- Second normal dialog with panel, progress bar, title and msg

It is just a class, so not a customizable library which u can import in your project, so you need to copy it and change it how you want.
It is a DialogFragment class, but you can use it inside an activity as a normal fragment just like you do with classic fragment by using FragmentManager.

## Code of the dialog class:

```
public class ProgressBarDialog extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = ProgressBarDialog.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String KEY = TAG.concat(".key");
// Argument Keys
private static final String KEY_DIALOG_TYPE = KEY.concat(".dialogType");
private static final String KEY_TITLE = KEY.concat(".title");
private static final String KEY_PROGRESS_TEXT = KEY.concat(".progressText");
private static final String KEY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_BUILDER = KEY.concat(".customLayoutBuilder");
// Class Names
private static final String CLASS_GRADIENT_STATE = "GradientState";
// Field Names
private static final String FIELD_THICKNESS = "mThickness";
private static final String FIELD_INNER_RADIUS = "mInnerRadius";

/** Dialog Types **/
private static final int TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_NO_ANIM = 0x0;
private static final int TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_ROTATE_ANIM = 0x1;
private static final int TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_FADE_ANIM = 0x2;
private static final int TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_AND_MSG = 0xF;

/** Animations Values **/
private static final long CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_ANIMATION_DURATION = 250L;
private static final long CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_START_OFFSET_MULTIPLIER = 250L;

private MaterialProgressBar mProgressBar;
private LinearLayout mllTextContainer;
private TextView mtvTitle;
private TextView mtvProgressText;

private List<TextView> mCenterTextViews;
private int mDialogType;
private String mTitle;
private String mProgressText;
private CustomLayoutBuilder mCustomLayoutBuilder;

/** Public Static Factory Methods **/
public static ProgressBarDialog initLayoutProgressBarOnlyNoAnim(String text, CustomLayoutBuilder builder){
    return initLayoutProgressBarOnly(TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_NO_ANIM, text, builder);
}

public static ProgressBarDialog initLayoutProgressBarOnlyRotateAnim(String text, CustomLayoutBuilder builder){
    return initLayoutProgressBarOnly(TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_ROTATE_ANIM, text, builder);
}

public static ProgressBarDialog initLayoutProgressBarOnlyFadeAnim(String text, CustomLayoutBuilder builder){
    return initLayoutProgressBarOnly(TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_FADE_ANIM, text, builder);
}

public static ProgressBarDialog initLayoutProgressBarAndMsg(String title, String text, CustomLayoutBuilder builder){
    ProgressBarDialog mInstance = new ProgressBarDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_DIALOG_TYPE, TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_AND_MSG);
    args.putString(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.putString(KEY_PROGRESS_TEXT, text);
    args.putParcelable(KEY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_BUILDER, builder);
    mInstance.setArguments(args);
    return mInstance;
}

/** Private Static Factory Methods **/
private static ProgressBarDialog initLayoutProgressBarOnly(int animation, String text, CustomLayoutBuilder builder){
    ProgressBarDialog mInstance = new ProgressBarDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_DIALOG_TYPE, animation);
    args.putString(KEY_PROGRESS_TEXT, text);
    args.putParcelable(KEY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_BUILDER, builder);
    mInstance.setArguments(args);
    return mInstance;
}

/** Override Lifecycle Methods **/
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initData();
}

@Override @Nullable
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress_bar, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    if(getContext() != null && mCustomLayoutBuilder != null) {
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getLayoutResID()));
        initShapes();
    }
    return view;
}

private void initShapes(){
    if(mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable();
        for (int i = 0; i < layerDrawable.getNumberOfLayers(); i++) {
            if(layerDrawable.getDrawable(i) instanceof RotateDrawable) {
                RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = (RotateDrawable) layerDrawable.getDrawable(i);
                int[] fromToDeg = mCustomLayoutBuilder.getDegreesMatrixRow(i);
                if(fromToDeg.length > 0){
                    rotateDrawable.setFromDegrees(fromToDeg[CustomLayoutBuilder.INDEX_FROM_DEGREES]);
                    rotateDrawable.setToDegrees(fromToDeg[CustomLayoutBuilder.INDEX_TO_DEGREES]);
                }
                if(rotateDrawable.getDrawable() instanceof GradientDrawable){
                    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) rotateDrawable.getDrawable();
                    int innerRadius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getInnerRadius(i));
                    if(mDialogType == TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_AND_MSG){
                        innerRadius /= 3;
                    }
                    int thickness = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getThickness(i));
                    int[] colors = mCustomLayoutBuilder.getColorsMatrixRow(i);
                    if(colors.length > 0x0){
                        gradientDrawable.setColors(DataUtils.resourcesIDsToColors(this.getContext(), colors));
                    }
                    if(innerRadius != -0x1){
                        DataUtils.setSubClassFieldIntValue(gradientDrawable.getConstantState(), gradientDrawable.getClass(), CLASS_GRADIENT_STATE, FIELD_INNER_RADIUS, innerRadius);
                    }
                    if(thickness != -0x1){
                        DataUtils.setSubClassFieldIntValue(gradientDrawable.getConstantState(), gradientDrawable.getClass(), CLASS_GRADIENT_STATE, FIELD_THICKNESS, thickness);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setWindowSize();
    startAnimation();
}

/** Public Methods **/
public void changeTextViews(String progressText){
    mProgressText = progressText;
    initTextViews();
    startAnimation();
}

public String getProgressText(){
    return mProgressText;
}

/** Private Methods **//** Init Methods **/
private void initData(){
    if(getArguments() != null) {
        if (getArguments().containsKey(KEY_DIALOG_TYPE)) {
            mDialogType = getArguments().getInt(KEY_DIALOG_TYPE);
        }
        if(getArguments().containsKey(KEY_TITLE)){
            mTitle = getArguments().getString(KEY_TITLE);
        }
        if (getArguments().containsKey(KEY_PROGRESS_TEXT)) {
            mProgressText = getArguments().getString(KEY_PROGRESS_TEXT);
        }
        if (getArguments().containsKey(KEY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_BUILDER)){
            mCustomLayoutBuilder = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT_BUILDER);
        }
    }
    mCenterTextViews = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void initViews(View layout){
    if(layout != null){
        switch(mDialogType){
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_NO_ANIM:
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_ROTATE_ANIM:
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_FADE_ANIM:
                if(getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
                    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }
                LinearLayout mLayoutProgressBarOnly = layout.findViewById(R.id.layout_progress_bar_only);
                mLayoutProgressBarOnly.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar = layout.findViewById(R.id.dpb_progress_bar);
                if(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressBarWidthDimen() != -0x1){
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mProgressBar.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressBarWidthDimen());
                    lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressBarHeightDimen());
                    mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
                mllTextContainer = layout.findViewById(R.id.dpb_text_container);
                initTextViews();
                break;
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_AND_MSG:
                LinearLayout mLayoutProgressBarAndMsg = layout.findViewById(R.id.layout_progress_bar_and_msg);
                mLayoutProgressBarAndMsg.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar = layout.findViewById(R.id.dpb_progress_bar_and_msg);
                mtvTitle = layout.findViewById(R.id.pbd_title);
                mtvProgressText = layout.findViewById(R.id.dpb_progress_msg);
                initProgressMsg();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void initTextViews(){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mProgressText)){
        clearTextContainer();
        for(char digit : mProgressText.toCharArray()){
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext(), null, 0x0, R.style.PBDCenterTextStyleWhite);
            if(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgColor() != CustomLayoutBuilder.DEFAULT_COLOR && getContext() != null){
                tv.setTextColor(ActivityCompat.getColor(getContext(), mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgColor()));
            }
            if(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgDimen() != CustomLayoutBuilder.DEFAULT_DIMEN){
                tv.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgDimen()));
            }
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(digit));
            mCenterTextViews.add(tv);
            mllTextContainer.addView(tv);
        }
    }
}

private void initProgressMsg(){
    mtvTitle.setText(mTitle);
    mtvProgressText.setText(mProgressText);
    if(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgColor() != CustomLayoutBuilder.DEFAULT_COLOR){
        mtvProgressText.setTextColor(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgColor());
    }
    if(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgDimen() != CustomLayoutBuilder.DEFAULT_DIMEN){
        mtvProgressText.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(mCustomLayoutBuilder.getProgressMsgDimen()));
    }
}

private void clearTextContainer(){
    if(mllTextContainer.getChildCount() >= 0x0){
        for(int i=0; i < mllTextContainer.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v = mllTextContainer.getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof TextView){
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                if(tv.getAnimation() != null){
                    tv.clearAnimation();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mllTextContainer.removeAllViews();
}

private void setWindowSize(){
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if(dialog != null && dialog.getWindow() != null){
        int width = 0x0, height = 0x0;
        switch(mDialogType){
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_NO_ANIM:
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_ROTATE_ANIM:
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_FADE_ANIM:
                width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;        //getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pbd_window_width);
                height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;       //getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pbd_window_height);
                break;
            case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_AND_MSG:
                width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;       //getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pbd_textual_window_height);
                break;
        }
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}

/** Animation Methods **/
private void startAnimation(){
    switch(mDialogType){
        case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_ROTATE_ANIM:
        startRotateAnimations();
        break;
        case TYPE_PROGRESS_BAR_ONLY_FADE_ANIM:
        startFadeInAnimations();
        break;
    }
}

private void startRotateAnimations(){
    for(TextView tv : mCenterTextViews){
        if(tv != null && tv.getText() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(tv.getText().toString().trim())) {
            int i = mCenterTextViews.indexOf(tv);
            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setDuration(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_ANIMATION_DURATION);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setStartOffset(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_START_OFFSET_MULTIPLIER * i);
            if (i == (mCenterTextViews.size() - 0x1)) {
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        startRotateAnimations();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
            tv.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}

private void startFadeInAnimations(){
    for(TextView tv : mCenterTextViews){
        if(tv != null && tv.getText() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(tv.getText().toString().trim())) {
            int i = mCenterTextViews.indexOf(tv);
            AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0x1, 0x0);
            anim.setDuration(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_ANIMATION_DURATION);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setStartOffset(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_START_OFFSET_MULTIPLIER * i);
            if (i == (mCenterTextViews.size() - 0x1)) {
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        startFadeOutAnimations();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
            tv.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}

private void startFadeOutAnimations(){
    for(TextView tv : mCenterTextViews){
        int i = mCenterTextViews.indexOf(tv);
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0x0, 0x1);
        anim.setDuration(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setStartOffset(CENTER_TEXT_VIEWS_START_OFFSET_MULTIPLIER * i);
        if(i == (mCenterTextViews.size() - 0x1)){
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    startFadeInAnimations();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        }
        tv.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}

/** Progress Bar Custom Layout Builder Class **/
public static class CustomLayoutBuilder implements Parcelable {

    /** Shapes **/
    private static final int RING = GradientDrawable.RING;

    /** Colors **/
    private static final int[][] COLORS_MATRIX_RYGB = new int[][]{
        new int[]{ R.color.transparent, R.color.transparent, R.color.material_red_A700 },
        new int[]{ R.color.transparent, R.color.transparent, R.color.material_amber_A700 },
        new int[]{ R.color.transparent, R.color.transparent, R.color.material_light_green_A700 },
        new int[]{ R.color.transparent, R.color.transparent, R.color.material_blue_A700 }
    };
    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = -0x1;

    /** Dimens **/
    private static final int DEFAULT_DIMEN = -0x1;
    private static final int[] DEFAULT_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMEN = new int[]{};

    /** Indexes **/
    private static final int INDEX_PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH = 0x0;
    private static final int INDEX_PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT = 0x1;
    private static final int INDEX_FROM_DEGREES = 0x0;
    private static final int INDEX_TO_DEGREES = 0x1;

    /** Arrays Sizes **/
    private static final int SIZE_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMENS_ARRAY = 0x2;

    /** Matrix Columns Number **/
    private static final int NUM_COLUMNS_DEGREES_MATRIX = 0x2;      /* Degrees Matrix Index                     ->  degrees[3]  =   { fromDegrees, toDegrees } */
    private static final int NUM_COLUMNS_COLORS_MATRIX = 0x3;       /* GradientDrawable Colors Matrix Index     ->  colors[3]   =   { startColor, centerColor, endColor } */

    /** Drawables Layout Resource IDs **/
    private static final int LAYOUT_RES_PROGRESS_BAR_RINGS = R.drawable.progress_bar_rings;

    /** Layout Data: Four Rings Overlaid **/
    private static final int RINGS_OVERLAID_LAYERS = 0x4;
    private static final int[][] RINGS_OVERLAID_DEGREES = new int[][]{ new int[]{ 300, 660 }, new int[]{ 210, 570 }, new int[]{ 120, 480 }, new int[]{ 30, 390 } };
    private static final int[] RINGS_OVERLAID_SHAPES = new int[]{ RING, RING, RING, RING };
    private static final int[] RINGS_OVERLAID_INNER_RADIUS = new int[]{ R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_60dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_60dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_60dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_60dp};
    private static final int[] RINGS_OVERLAID_THICKNESS = new int[]{ R.dimen.pbd_thickness_40dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_30dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_20dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_10dp };

    /** Layout Data: Four Rings Spaced **/
    private static final int RINGS_SPACED_LAYERS = 0x4;
    private static final int[][] RINGS_SPACED_DEGREES = new int[][]{ new int[]{ 180, 540 }, new int[]{ 0, 360 }, new int[]{ 90, 450 }, new int[]{ 270, 630 } };
    private static final int[] RINGS_SPACED_SHAPES = new int[]{ RING, RING, RING, RING };
    private static final int[] RINGS_SPACED_INNER_RADIUS = new int[]{ R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_30dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_60dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_90dp, R.dimen.pbd_inner_radius_120dp };
    private static final int[] RINGS_SPACED_THICKNESS = new int[]{ R.dimen.pbd_thickness_10dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_15dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_20dp, R.dimen.pbd_thickness_25dp };

    private int mLayoutResID;
    private int[] mProgressBarDimens;
    private int mNumLayers;
    private int[][] mRotateDegrees;
    private int[] mShapes;
    private int[] mInnerRadius;
    private int[] mThickness;
    private int[][] mColors;
    private int mProgressMsgColor;
    private int mProgressMsgDimen;

    public static Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new CreatorCustomLayoutBuilder();

    /** Constructors **/
    private CustomLayoutBuilder(int layoutResID, int[] progressBarDimens, int numLayers, int[][] degreesMatrix, int[] shapes, int[] innerRadius, int[] thickness,
                                int[][] colorsMatrix, int msgColor, int progressMsgDimen){
        mLayoutResID = layoutResID;
        mProgressBarDimens = progressBarDimens;
        mNumLayers = numLayers;
        mRotateDegrees = degreesMatrix;
        mShapes = shapes;
        mInnerRadius = innerRadius;
        mThickness = thickness;
        mColors = colorsMatrix;
        mProgressMsgColor = msgColor;
        mProgressMsgDimen = progressMsgDimen;
    }

    private CustomLayoutBuilder(Parcel in){
        mLayoutResID = in.readInt();
        mProgressBarDimens = new int[SIZE_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMENS_ARRAY];
        in.readIntArray(mProgressBarDimens);
        mNumLayers = in.readInt();
        int[] tempArray = new int[NUM_COLUMNS_DEGREES_MATRIX * mNumLayers];
        in.readIntArray(tempArray);
        mRotateDegrees = DataUtils.arrayToMatrix(tempArray, NUM_COLUMNS_DEGREES_MATRIX);
        mShapes = new int[mNumLayers];
        in.readIntArray(mShapes);
        mInnerRadius = new int[mNumLayers];
        in.readIntArray(mInnerRadius);
        mThickness = new int[mNumLayers];
        in.readIntArray(mThickness);
        tempArray = new int[NUM_COLUMNS_COLORS_MATRIX * mNumLayers];
        in.readIntArray(tempArray);
        mColors = DataUtils.arrayToMatrix(tempArray, NUM_COLUMNS_COLORS_MATRIX);
        mProgressMsgColor = in.readInt();
        mProgressMsgDimen = in.readInt();
    }

    /** Public Static Factory Methods **/
    public static CustomLayoutBuilder initLayoutRingsOverlaid(){
        return new CustomLayoutBuilder(LAYOUT_RES_PROGRESS_BAR_RINGS, DEFAULT_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMEN, RINGS_OVERLAID_LAYERS, RINGS_OVERLAID_DEGREES, RINGS_OVERLAID_SHAPES,
                RINGS_OVERLAID_INNER_RADIUS, RINGS_OVERLAID_THICKNESS, COLORS_MATRIX_RYGB, R.color.material_white, DEFAULT_DIMEN);
    }

    public static CustomLayoutBuilder initLayoutRingsOverlaid(int[] resProgBarDimens, int resProgMsgColor, int resProgMsgDimen){
        return new CustomLayoutBuilder(LAYOUT_RES_PROGRESS_BAR_RINGS, resProgBarDimens, RINGS_OVERLAID_LAYERS, RINGS_OVERLAID_DEGREES, RINGS_OVERLAID_SHAPES,
                RINGS_OVERLAID_INNER_RADIUS, RINGS_OVERLAID_THICKNESS, COLORS_MATRIX_RYGB, resProgMsgColor, resProgMsgDimen);
    }

    public static CustomLayoutBuilder initLayoutRingsSpaced(){
        return new CustomLayoutBuilder(LAYOUT_RES_PROGRESS_BAR_RINGS, DEFAULT_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMEN, RINGS_SPACED_LAYERS, RINGS_SPACED_DEGREES, RINGS_SPACED_SHAPES,
                RINGS_SPACED_INNER_RADIUS, RINGS_SPACED_THICKNESS, COLORS_MATRIX_RYGB, DEFAULT_COLOR, DEFAULT_DIMEN);
    }

    /** Override Parcelable Methods **/
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(mLayoutResID);
        out.writeIntArray(mProgressBarDimens);
        out.writeInt(mNumLayers);
        out.writeIntArray(DataUtils.matrixToArray(mRotateDegrees));
        out.writeIntArray(mShapes);
        out.writeIntArray(mInnerRadius);
        out.writeIntArray(mThickness);
        out.writeIntArray(DataUtils.matrixToArray(mColors));
        out.writeInt(mProgressMsgColor);
        out.writeInt(mProgressMsgDimen);
    }

    /** Getter & Setter Methods **/
    private int getLayoutResID() {
        return mLayoutResID;
    }

    private void setLayoutResID(int layoutResID) {
        this.mLayoutResID = layoutResID;
    }

    private int[] getProgressBarDimens() {
        return mProgressBarDimens;
    }

    private void setProgressBarDimens(int[] progressBarDimens) {
        this.mProgressBarDimens = progressBarDimens;
    }

    private int getProgressBarWidthDimen(){         // Used to check if 'mProgressBarDimens' array is set.
        if(mProgressBarDimens != null && mProgressBarDimens.length == SIZE_PROGRESS_BAR_DIMENS_ARRAY){
            return mProgressBarDimens[INDEX_PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH];
        } else {
            return -0x1;
        }
    }

    private int getProgressBarHeightDimen(){
        return mProgressBarDimens[INDEX_PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT];
    }

    private int getNumLayers() {
        return mNumLayers;
    }

    private void setNumLayers(int numLayers) {
        this.mNumLayers = numLayers;
    }

    private int[][] getRotateDegrees() {
        return mRotateDegrees;
    }

    private void setRotateDegrees(int[][] rotateDegrees) {
        this.mRotateDegrees = rotateDegrees;
    }

    private int[] getShapes() {
        return mShapes;
    }

    private void setShapes(int[] shapes) {
        this.mShapes = shapes;
    }

    private int[] getInnerRadius() {
        return mInnerRadius;
    }

    private void setInnerRadius(int[] innerRadius) {
        this.mInnerRadius = innerRadius;
    }

    private int[] getThickness() {
        return mThickness;
    }

    private void setThickness(int[] thickness) {
        this.mThickness = thickness;
    }

    private int[][] getColorsMatrix() {
        return mColors;
    }

    private void setColorsMatrix(int[][] colorsMatrix) {
        this.mColors = colorsMatrix;
    }

    private int getProgressMsgColor() {
        return mProgressMsgColor;
    }

    private void setProgressMsgColor(int progressMsgColor) {
        this.mProgressMsgColor = progressMsgColor;
    }

    private int getProgressMsgDimen() {
        return mProgressMsgDimen;
    }

    private void setProgressMsgDimen(int progressMsgDimen) {
        this.mProgressMsgDimen = progressMsgDimen;
    }

    /** Public Methods **/
    private int[] getDegreesMatrixRow(int numRow){
        if(mRotateDegrees != null && mRotateDegrees.length > numRow) {
            return mRotateDegrees[numRow];
        } else {
            return new int[]{};
        }
    }

    private int getShape(int position){
        if(mShapes != null && mShapes.length > position){
            return mShapes[position];
        } else {
            return -0x1;
        }
    }

    private int getInnerRadius(int position){
        if(mInnerRadius != null && mInnerRadius.length > position){
            return mInnerRadius[position];
        } else {
            return -0x1;
        }
    }

    private int getThickness(int position){
        if(mThickness != null && mThickness.length > position){
            return mThickness[position];
        } else {
            return -0x1;
        }
    }

    private int[] getColorsMatrixRow(int numRow) {
        if(mColors != null && mColors.length > numRow){
            return mColors[numRow];
        } else {
            return new int[]{};
        }
    }

    /** Private Static Class Parcelable Creator **/
    private static class CreatorCustomLayoutBuilder implements Parcelable.Creator<CustomLayoutBuilder> {

        @Override
        public CustomLayoutBuilder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CustomLayoutBuilder(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CustomLayoutBuilder[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CustomLayoutBuilder[size];
        }

    }

}
}
```

- The class has a progress bar with no dialog and custom text over it.
  The text can have 2 animations:
- Fade In -> Fade Out animation: digits will fade out like a sequentially from left to right. At end of text will restart from left.
- Rotate Animation: same sequential behavior but the digits rotate on themself one by one instead of fading out.
- Other way is a Progress Bar with a dialog (Title + Message)

[image: Rotation Animation]

[image: Dialog Progress Bar]

Comment: Over 30K chars lol...
I can't add layouts and other things.. PM me if you need them (: Bye

Answer (score 0):

## Rest of code

## Code of utils methods:

```
public static int[] resourcesIDsToColors(Context context, int[] resIDs){
            int[] colors = new int[resIDs.length];
            for(int i=0; i < resIDs.length; i++){
                colors[i] = ActivityCompat.getColor(context, resIDs[i]);
            }
            return colors;
        }
    
    public static void setSubClassFieldIntValue(Object objField, Class<?> superClass, String subName, String fieldName, int fieldValue){
            Class<?> subClass = getSubClass(superClass, subName);
            if(subClass != null) {
                Field field = getClassField(subClass, fieldName);
                if (field != null) {
                    setFieldValue(objField, field, fieldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public static Class<?> getSubClass(Class<?> superClass, String subName){
            Class<?>[] classes = superClass.getDeclaredClasses();
            if(classes != null && classes.length > 0){
                for(Class<?> clss : classes){
                    if(clss.getSimpleName().equals(subName)){
                        return clss;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        public static Field getClassField(Class<?> clss, String fieldName){
            try {
                Field field = clss.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field;
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfE) {
                Log.e(TAG, nsfE.getMessage());
            } catch (SecurityException sE){
                Log.e(TAG, sE.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    public static int[][] arrayToMatrix(int[] array, int numColumns){
            int numRows = array.length / numColumns;
            int[][] matrix = new int[numRows][numColumns];
            int nElemens = array.length;
            for(int i=0; i < nElemens; i++){
                matrix[i / numColumns][i % numColumns] = array[i];
            }
            return matrix;
        }

public static int[] matrixToArray(int[][] matrix){
        /** [+] Square matrix of order n        ->      A matrix with n rows and n columns, same number of rows and columns.
         *  [+] Matrix rows & columns number annotations:
         *          matrix[rows][columns]           matrix (rows x columns)         matrix rows, columns        rows by columns matrix
         * **/
        int numRows = matrix.length;
        int[] arr = new int[]{};
        for(int i=0; i < numRows; i++){
            int numColumns = matrix[i].length;
            int[] row = new int[numColumns];
            for(int j=0; j < numColumns; j++){
                row[j] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            arr = ArrayUtils.addAll(arr, row);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

## Code of default layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_progress_bar_only"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/dpb_constraint_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/dpb_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/pbd_progressbar_width_2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pbd_progressbar_height_2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dpb_text_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_progress_bar_and_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/PBDTextualMainLayoutStyle">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/pbd_textual_card_elevation">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pbd_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/PBDTextualTitle"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pbd_textual_main_layout_height"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/pbd_textual_progressbar_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pbd_textual_progressbar_height">
                <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/dpb_progress_bar_and_msg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="@style/PBDProgressBarStyle"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pbd_textual_msg_container_height">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dpb_progress_msg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="@style/PBDTextualProgressMsgStyle"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

## Progress Bar Rings:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="300"
            android:toDegrees="660">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="210"
            android:toDegrees="570">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="120"
            android:toDegrees="480">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:startColor="#00000000"
                    android:centerColor="#00000000"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="30"
            android:toDegrees="390">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <solid android:color="#000000"/>
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

## Dimens Resources:

```
 <!-- ProgressBarDialog Dimens (Normal & Textual Versions) -->
        <dimen name="pbd_window_width">250dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_window_height">250dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_progressbar_width_1">250dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_progressbar_height_1">250dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_progressbar_width_2">400dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_progressbar_height_2">400dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_window_height">170dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_main_layout_height">150dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_progressbar_width">150dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_progressbar_height">150dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_msg_container_height">150dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_main_layout_margin_horizontal">50dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_main_layout_padding_horizontal">5dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_main_layout_padding_bottom">15dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_title_padding">4dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_msg_container_margin">3dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_msg_container_padding">3dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_card_elevation">15dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_textual_progressmsg_padding_start">10dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_inner_radius_30dp">30dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_inner_radius_60dp">60dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_inner_radius_90dp">90dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_inner_radius_120dp">120dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_40dp">40dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_30dp">30dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_25dp">25dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_20dp">20dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_15dp">15dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="pbd_thickness_10dp">10dp</dimen>
```

## Styles Resources:

```
<!-- PROGRESS BAR DIALOG STYLES -->
    <style name="PBDCenterTextStyleWhite">
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PBDTextualTitle">
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/pbd_textual_title_padding</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">start</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PBDTextualProgressMsgStyle">
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_black</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal|italic</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/pbd_textual_progressmsg_padding_start</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">start</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_yellow_A100</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PBDTextualMainLayoutStyle">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/pbd_textual_main_layout_padding_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/pbd_textual_main_layout_padding_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/pbd_textual_main_layout_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PBDProgressBarStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```