# Denote progress by border Android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I need to denote progress by the border of view.
E.g. Initially view will not have any border at all, when 50% progress is reached, only 50% of view will get border.Find the attached image.
I did lot of googling but no luck.The view I used is textview.

[image]

**Edited**

The following code, cuts the edges of bitmap.
What I've done in this code is - 
1. Bg is set to Black Hexagon
2. And I've taken hollow green bordered hexagon & revealing this hollow hexagon, so that it will look like border is getting accumulated.

```
public class MyView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Paint mPaint;
private RectF mOval;
private float mAngle = 135;
private Paint mTextPaint;
private Bitmap bgBitmap;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    doInit();
}


/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyleAttr
 */
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    doInit();
}


/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    doInit();
}

private void doInit() {
    // use your bitmap insted of R.drawable.ic_launcher
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexagon_border);
    bgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.view_message_small_hexagon);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mOval = new RectF();
    mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(48);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    mTextPaint.setColor(0xffffaa00);
    mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
    RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    m.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    Shader shader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    shader.setLocalMatrix(m);
    mPaint.setShader(shader);
    m.mapRect(mOval, src);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //canvas.drawColor(0xff0000aa);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, matrix, null);
    canvas.drawArc(mOval, -90, mAngle, true, mPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float w2 = getWidth() / 2f;
    float h2 = getHeight() / 2f;
    mAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - h2, event.getX() - w2));
    mAngle += 90 + 360;
    mAngle %= 360;
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710613/how-do-i-draw-a-partial-bitmap-arc-like-a-circular-progress-wheel-but-with-a-b

Comment: I've gone through your code, but did not understand what changes should be done to make it work as expected.

Comment: think for a while, now you have solution how to clip one bitmao in a radial way, what next?

Comment: @pskink I have edited my question.The only issue I'm facing now is edges of the hexagon getting cut.Do you have any clue regarding why it is happening?

Answer (score 2):

try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710613/how-do-i-draw-a-partial-bitmap-arc-like-a-circular-progress-wheel-but-with-a-b):

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private RectF mOval;
    private float mAngle = 135;
    private Paint mTextPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // use your bitmap insted of R.drawable.ic_launcher
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mOval = new RectF();
        mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(48);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setColor(0xffffaa00);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        m.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        Shader shader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
        shader.setLocalMatrix(m);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);
        m.mapRect(mOval, src);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xff0000aa);
        canvas.drawArc(mOval, -90, mAngle, true, mPaint);
        canvas.drawText("click me", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mTextPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float w2 = getWidth() / 2f;
        float h2 = getHeight() / 2f;
        mAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - h2, event.getX() - w2));
        mAngle += 90 + 360;
        mAngle %= 360;
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't tried this code...but I think this will draw oval around view.right?

Comment: It is supposed to reveal your bitmap in an oval way.

Comment: I dont want to reveal the image,I want to draw border around it.

Comment: @VishalPawale this code does what you need, you just have to add one small thing to that code

Comment: Okay...then..I will try it...will make changes as needed and will let you know

Comment: Thanks Guys for your suggestions, I got it working but edges of the bitmap are getting cut.I have edited my question with latest code.Can you suggest me a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a good circular progress spinner is difficult in itself. The [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) is a good custom `View` that does this. You should be able to modify the [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel/blob/master/src/com/todddavies/components/progressbar/ProgressWheel.java)'s onDraw() class to do something very similar to what you want.