# Android Circular UI Progress Elements

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Ok so. I'm trying to build a nice Android Wear app with a companion app and I cannot for the life of me find a none animated circle element. To be clear this is what I'm looking for.

[image: Multistage circle graphs in Google Fit App]

[image: Single stage battrey level graph]

They appear to be fairly basic elements however they're not in the palette of available default elements despite showing up in a lot of apps and watch faces from a myriad of developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Material Progress Bar https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress

OR

[Try this link.](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76) Choose one of the progress bar as you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

And set it as android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" to your progressbar.

Comment: still animating infinitely

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is not a default element.
Basically you have 2 options.
1. Go and find something suitable here https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76. Don't worry about extra dependency it usually consists of 1-5 classes for custom view.
2. You can create your own custom view, using [Canvas.drawArc(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)) method.

Also here are couple of links to help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26806770/1527472
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Comment: You are also legend. Android Arsenal looks to be the go to resource for standard non-standard and non-standard elements. :D Thanks for the link.

However Sharma provided the direct solution to my problem today so he gets the cred. :)