# setProgress not working for android progressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to set the progress of a progress bar but it just keeps spinning, do I need to add something or how to I set it to be a certain percentage?

Code:

```
public class TabOverviewFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.progressBar1)
ProgressBar progressBar1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_overview,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    progressBar1.setProgress(90);
    return view;

}
public TabOverviewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".modinfosection.TabOverviewFragment">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"

    android:scrollbarSize="300dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below property in your **`ProgressBar`**

```
android:indeterminateOnly="true"
```

> [**`android:indeterminateOnly`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateOnly)

- Restricts to ONLY indeterminate mode (state-keeping progress mode will not work).

> if you want **`Horizontal-ProgressBar`** than use below property

- `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true" 
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:scrollbarSize="300dp"/>
```

Comment: So there is no way to make the circle progress bar be at a certain percentage? Reason I'm asking is because I want to use it around a picture, something like this: https://imgur.com/dt9CcnV

Comment: @Erbez yes that is possible check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47977523/7666442

Answer (score 1):

Update `ProgressBar` to this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="300dp"/>
```

You need to give `ProgressBar` determinate style to use it as percent progress.

More from here : [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#determinate-progress)

Comment: So there is no way to make the circle progress bar be at a certain percentage? Reason I'm asking is because I want to use it around a picture, something like this: https://imgur.com/dt9CcnV