# How to create custom progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

How to create custom progress bar like this? I attached image. Give some ideas..[image]

```
              <at.grabner.circleprogress.CircleProgressView
                android:id="@+id/timer_circleView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/progress_bar"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                CircleProgressView:barWidth="12dp"
                CircleProgressView:contourSize="0dp"
                CircleProgressView:rimWidth="122dp"
                CircleProgressView:barColor1="#e7e2e2"
                CircleProgressView:barColor="#d60d25"
                CircleProgressView:seekMode="true"
                CircleProgressView:text="2dffff0"
                CircleProgressView:textSize="15dp"
                CircleProgressView:textColor="#d60d25" />
```

Comment: show us your efforts, post your code and tell what you have tried.

Comment: @RatilalChopda . check my above code. Previously im not using custom progress bar.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android) this will help u

Comment: @ArjunParth. having doubt in this part. in that image how to make shaded in center circle?