# Circular progressbar

Tags: android, android-animation, android-progressbar, android-assets

I want to create a circular progressbar, like in this image below 
[image: Circle Progress Bar]

I don't know what the method that creates this progressbar is. And I don't know what assets should be prepared.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at this sample you will be having nice sample here:

[Todd-Davies | ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

It will be look like following images.

[image: Sample 1]
 [image: Sample 2]
 [image: Sample 3]
 [image: Sample 4]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: HI this is working fine i am implementing ontouch methode in this i am call incrementProgress() in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is call forword but i need both forward and back,how to do this please help me..

Comment: Hi itsrajesh, this code is very nice.. i need some changes in this code. i want change the color for circle progress. i could not do.what i want for, at runtime,when progress is crossed particular percentage,i need to change the circle bar color.. pls if possible help me..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an ArcView [Link](https://github.com/minsoopark/ArcView).

It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following link.. I will be helpful for you.. We need to customize the views to create a new one.. Instead of customizing our own view we can add library projects and and use the views..

Follow this for library project,

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/holo-circular-progressbar/

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/02/circular-seekbar/

And this for customizing our own view,

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Answer (score 1):

try this method to draw a bitmap and set it to image view. use it in a dialog to create a circular progress dialog.

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {


    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);

        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 

        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a custom view . about assets i guess all you need is some color codes . create a class extends View . add method setProgress(int) . in OnDraw() draw one filled circle . and one arc from 0 to _progress . drawText progress at center . you can find sample code easily . search for it .