# How to implement this type of Progressbar in android using xml file

Tags: android, styles, progress-bar

How to apply glow effect?

I am trying to create this type of horizontal `ProgressBar` but no idea about the glowing effect for as starting point of progress.

[image]

Here is my code for gradient color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />

        <solid android:color="#ff9d9e9d"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

            <gradient
                    android:angle="180"
                    android:startColor="#8872f8fc"
                    android:endColor="#886dc0e3" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="180"
                    android:startColor="#31c6f7"
                    android:centerColor="#2ea6d1"
                    android:endColor="#2884a6" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898185/holo-progressbar-glow-effect

Comment: U should check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog

Comment: How did you achieve to add the percentage below to align it correctly with the progress bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a png image for glowing head. Use < bitmap> tag inside the layer-list and     align it to right. I did a similar thing for a completely different application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#4C4C4C"
            android:startColor="#303030" />

        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:top="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:gravity="right|bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/spinner_down_arrow" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The glow effects are png drawables with transparency. Layed on top of the right side of current process.

Create a custom view progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add an ImageView to your layout. Create the drawables for progress bars. Then draw inside the ImageView with 2 layers by code. First layer would be background and the second layer would be the knob. Write redrawing code to the onTouch Listener of imageview to update view as touched.