# Holo progressbar glow effect

Tags: android, canvas

I'm using canvas to draw my custom shape, and I want to add glow effect on it's end like in Android Progressbar View. I tried to look at Android sources, but did not found how exactly such effect is achieved.

[image: Desireble effect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glow effect is part of the PNG image, see its [source file](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-4.2_r2/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/progress_primary_holo_light.9.png). It is used (indirectly via [drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_light](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-4.2_r2/core/res/res/drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_light.xml)) as value of [android:progressDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android%3aprogressDrawable).

Comment: No, the glow effect is part of the image and has been done in Photoshop. But notice how they cleverly use a nine-patch image that can be stretched to an arbitrary width while preserving the glow effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the glowing by using a [BlurMaskFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.html) which can be used via [`paint.setFilterMask(maskFilter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setMaskFilter%28android.graphics.MaskFilter%29).

You might need to make multiple draws with different filters to achieve some cool effects.

Comment: setMaskFilter() is not hardware accelerated, so i need to disable HWA on my view to make it work, right?

Comment: No, Android will take care of that. You could create a bitmap of your stuff as a cache and use that for drawing. This should be supported by HWA again.