# How to get an array of images?

Tags: android, arrays, android-imageview, batterylevel

I want to make a Battery app which should notify the battery percentage to user in form of image. Now for battery percentage 0-100, I need 101 images in all. What I want to do is that is it possible to insert all these images in an array and use them accordingly. For instance, if my battery percentage is 47%, the image in array at position 47 should be the resource.
That is, suppose I have **ImageView named Battery**, and I have an **array named batteryimage(containing all the 101 images)** then I should be able to do this,

```
Battery.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.batteryimage[p])
```

where **p** will be the current percentage of battery, which I will get by code.

Hope you all understood what I want.. Thanx in advance..

Comment: 100 images? really? of course it's up to you, but it would be much better to think about reusing one image to display progress.

Comment: i was just thinking that, overlay transparent images and just use 0 - 100 % bounds of one of the images, youll be better off memory wise alot more pros than cons

Answer (score 14, accepted):

define a array of image id like this

```
int[] p = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2....}
```

now for different condition use member of this array like

```
Battery.setBackgroundResource(p[0])  // or p[1]
```

or you can use ENUM to make it more readable..

But.. I think you should think in another way. instead of using 100 different image create a custom progressbar to show different state of your battery.

To know the basics of Progress bar see doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)
and to create custom progressbar you can check this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)

Comment: Yes and it's worth to note that you can't really do it in other way. Only by manually writing all images' ids.