# progress bar - no info just loading bar

Tags: android, text, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Below is my code for just a simple progress bar.

My questions are:

- How do I delete the text/information that appears on that pop-up progress bar, so there is ony the yelow bar?
- And also, can I change the color from yellow to blue?

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button btnStartProgress;
  ProgressDialog progressBar;
  private int progressBarStatus = 0;
  private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

  private long fileSize = 0;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

      addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

      btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
               new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

          // progress bar dialog
          progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
          progressBar.setCancelable(true);
          progressBar.setMessage("Progress Bar ... ");
          progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          progressBar.setProgress(0);
          progressBar.setMax(100);
          progressBar.show();

          //reset progress bar status
          progressBarStatus = 0;

          //reset filesize
          fileSize = 0;

          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                // process some tasks
                progressBarStatus = Tasks();


                try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Update the progress bar
                progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                  }
                });
              }

              // progress 100%
              if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                  // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                  try {
                      Thread.sleep(2000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  // close the progress bar dialog
                  progressBar.dismiss();
              }
            }
             }).start();

             }

              });

      }

  public int Tasks() {

      while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

          fileSize++;

          if (fileSize == 100000) {
              return 10;
          } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
              return 20;
          } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
              return 30;
          } else if (fileSize == 500000) {
              return 50;
          } else if (fileSize == 900000) {
              return 90;
          }

      }

      return 100;

  }}
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two nice tutorials about that:

[TUT1](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[TUT2](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/progress-bar-tutorial-for-android/)

For the customization of the ProgresDialog, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog). And also:

```
<style name="pbStyle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:background">#FF0000FF</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```