# ProgressBar is not showing in center of device when using indeterminateDrawable

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am working with custom progress bar using `indeterminateDrawable` property, code is below, when I removed `indeterminateDrawable` property then it shown in center but not shown center with this property. please help me.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/workingProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/startup_anim"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/startup_anim.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation4"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation3"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation2"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation0"
    android:duration="100"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: make your height and width=wrap_content

Comment: try giving it `layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of `android:layout_gravity`

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah and bakriOnFire Thanks for comment but I tried both way you suggested

Comment: may be sharing the `animation(s)` code can help us understand the problem.

Comment: it is working when I set height width to fix value

Comment: Is this problem specific to particular Android OS versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` while creating `ProgressBar`, it will stretch it and the result won't be as you expect. And if you want to center your `ProgressBar` in your `Activity` or `Fragment` just use this layout :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/workingProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/startup_anim"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this code also, when I set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"` its doesn't show anything

Comment: than set them to match_parent, it's probably something with your custom progress images.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23527028/252871) solves such issues by using a `<scale>` inside each `<item>` of an `<animation-list>` like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="100">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/img_1"
            android:scaleGravity="center"/>
    </item>
    <item android:duration="100">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/img_2"
            android:scaleGravity="center"/>
    </item>
</animation-list>
```