# Progress Dialog launches another AlertDialog

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I want to show another alert message(alert box/alert dialog) after the progress bar reaches 100%. How do I do that?

And Also is there any way to style that box (or both of them)?

Below is my code for an ProgressBar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button progress_button;
ProgressDialog pro_dialog;
Handler pro_handler;
int progress;
private static final int MAX_PROGRESS = 100; 


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

// intiliazing the buttons
progress_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
progress_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // Creating progress dialog interface setting
   // title,progressstyle,max_progress

pro_dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pro_dialog.setTitle("Making everything OK is in progress! Please be patient.");
pro_dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pro_dialog.setMax(MAX_PROGRESS);

progress = 0;
pro_dialog.show();
pro_dialog.setProgress(0);
pro_handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

  }
 });

 // set onclick listener for buttons

  pro_handler = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    if (progress >= MAX_PROGRESS) {
     pro_dialog.dismiss();
    } else {
     progress++;
     pro_dialog.incrementProgressBy(2);
     pro_handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
    }

   }
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would make more sense if you could replace:

```
pro_dialog.incrementProgressBy(2);
```

with this:

```
pro_dialog.setProgress(progress);
```

Current code dismisses dialog after progress variable reaches MAX_PROGRESS, but current value of this variable isn't presented by the progress dialog.

If you would like to show AlertDialog, you can do it for example after "pro_dialog.dismiss()".

Case of Progress Dialog styling has been discused [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog/4454450#4454450).

Comment: found this tutorial: [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/simple-alert-dialog-popup-with-title-message-icon-and-button), but don't know how to put that code, so that after the progress bar reaches 100%, it shows that AlertDialog. Any help?