# Create custom spinner in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to create a custom spinner that I want to re-use throughout my app. Hence, I want to create my spinner as an xml layout file (i.e. /layout/custom_spinner.xml). I have already created by drawable list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Now I need to know how to place it inside my spinner. The typical xml spinner looks like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

How do I accomplish what I want?

EDIT:

The following basically works, but it shows four progress spinners/bars instead of one in the center.

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The term `Spinner` in android refers to something other than a `ProgressBar`.

However, look at the `setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)` and `setIndeterminateDrawable(Drawable d)` methods.

You will need to remove this line

`style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"`

EDIT:

```
<rotate android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="360" />
```

I can't find the specific rotate drawable info in the docs so I am unsure what it needs to be wrapped in, if anything.

Comment: So do I treat my animation-list as a drawable? How do I do that?

Comment: There is also a method called setAnimation. I am not sure which one to use or how to use them.

Comment: @cote-mounyo, a `animation-list` is a drawable.  have alook at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog.  there are a number of answers.

Comment: Thanks for helping (+1). I suppose I am almost there. See my edit for the new problem I am having.

Comment: @CoteMounyo, do you want the rocketship to rotate?  the drawable i think will depend on the animating effect you wish to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I do. I want it to rotate.