# How to disable user interaction while ProgressBar is visible in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

I am using a custom ProgressBar. Now while a task is going on, I am showing the progress bar, but user can still interact with the views and controls. 
How do I disable the user interaction on whole view just like a ProgressDialog does , when it is visible.

Do I need to use a transparent view on top of main view and show the progress bar on that view and hide that view once a task is completed.

Or just get the id of my parentView and set it disabled ? But then I won't be able to dim the background, just like what happens when a dialog appears on the view/Activity/Fragment. Right?

I just want to know the way to disallow the user from any interaction while the progressbar is visible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)

Comment: @txteclipse  I do not want to customize progress bar, I have already done that. 
So, my question is not duplicate.
I just want to disable user interaction while the progress bar is visible, same way when a ProgressDialog is visible user cannot interact to other UI controls without dismissing the progress dialog.

Now how does my question is duplicate of that question. My question is not even remotely related to customization.

Comment: If you want all the functionality of a dialog, you should use a dialog. Modality is non-trivial to implement: the accepted answer doesn't block keyboard interaction, for instance. The second answer in the linked question demonstrates how to use custom ProgressBar resources with a ProgressDialog. If that doesn't fulfill your needs, you can use a [custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) with your ProgressBar.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

> Your question: How to disable the user interaction while ProgressBar is visible in android?

To disable the user interaction you just need to add the following code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To get user interaction back you just need to add the following code

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

> **Here is an example:**
>   **Note:I am giving you just an example to show how to disable or retain user interaction**

Add a progress bar in your xml.Something like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

In MainActivity when a button pressed you show the progressbar and disable the user interaction.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        }
    });
}
```

And when user backPressed you remove the progressbar again retain the user interaction.Something like this

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}
```

If you want to add a feature of disable and greyed out display, you need to add in your xml layout file a linear layout that fills the parent. Set its background to #B0000000 and its `visibilty` to `GONE`. Then programmatically set its `visibility` to `VISIBLE`.

Hope this help!

Comment: There is something interesting about this implementation. I'm developing a wearable app for a polar watch and this solution has been giving me some troubles. I noticed that whenever the user touches the screen fast if the action after such touch is blocking the UI using your solution (To prevent multiple events) for some reason android opens any app or option that is behind my app. To try to explain it a little better its like my app minimizes for a fraction of a second real quick and allows me to touch anything that is on the screen at that moment. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 15):

I have fixed this issue by adding root layout to the `ProgressBar`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/progress">
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/primary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Made the root layout clickable

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**NOTE:**  In my main view, I had `RelativeLayout` as root and have added above-mentioned code inside the root layout at the last position (last child).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I would suggest a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`, other than that, this answer is perfect and it just works. Thanks Nivar

Comment: Does this work when there are buttons in the background view? The elevation of those seems higher (api 21+ at least) and they will be clickable, unless you set a higher elevation in this root layout.

Answer (score 12):

just set:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

in your xml

```
<ProgressBar...
```

Only this makes magic!

Answer (score 6):

To extend (pun intended) on the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36927858/4687402) :

When you use kotlin you can use extension functions. That way you have a quick and nice looking method for blocking and unblocking UI.

```
fun AppCompatActivity.blockInput() {
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
}

fun AppCompatActivity.unblockInput() {
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
}

fun AppCompatActivity.blockInputForTask(task: () -> Unit) {
    blockInput()
    task.invoke()
    unblockInput()
}
```

You can use the blocking and unblocking functions in your activity. Also, you can add more functionality like showing a Toast or something.

When using it in a custom view or any other view, you can simply cast the context to activity and use the functions.

Use `blockInputForTask` to surround simple linear tasks and `blockInput`and `unblockInput` when they are needed in different scopes.

You can use `blockInputForTask` like this:

```
blockInputForTask { 
    // Your lines of code
    // Can be multiple lines
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to call any `suspend` function in the `task` you can change the `blockInputForTask()` signature: `suspend fun Activity.blockInputForTask(task: suspend () -> Unit)`

Answer (score 3):

Use document default method progressbar.setCancelable(false)

Comment: But what effect will it have on user interaction ? I can still touch or type in EditText while the ProgressBar is visible and is cancellable set to false.

Comment: and since when a progress bar started having setCancelable(false) property ?

Comment: U have option when your task running setenabled false as your parent view and after task done setenabled set as true

Answer (score 3):

Make a dialog with transparent background. The issue with  `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);` is that when app will go in background and come back user will be able to interact with UI components, a lot more handling. So for blocking UI make a transparent dialog and if you want to set time for hide/show. Do this in a runnable thread. So the solution will be

```
public class TransparentDialogHelper {

    private Dialog overlayDialog;

    @Inject
    public TransparentDialogHelper() {

    }

    public void showDialog(Context context) {
        if (AcmaUtility.isContextFinishing(context)) {
            return;
        }
        if (overlayDialog == null) {
            overlayDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
            overlayDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED);
        }
        overlayDialog.show();
    }

    public void hideDialog() {
        if (overlayDialog == null || AcmaUtility.isContextFinishing(overlayDialog.getContext())) {
            return;
        }
        overlayDialog.cancel();
    }
}

-------- Timer

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( () -> {
    view.hideProgress();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: excellent solution, maintains explicit  control over the process.  Oh yeah, and it woks, as well.   UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your parent layout as Relative Layout & add this :

```
    <RelativeLayout ... >

    <other layout elements over which prog bar will appear>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rl_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pb"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:indeterminateOnly="true"
             style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyProgressBar"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have floating buttons in your UI, they still grab all the focus & remain clickable when the progress bar is visible. for this use : (when your prog bar is visible & re-enable them when you make your prog bar invisible/gone)

```
fb.setEnabled(false);
```