# Is there an xml attribute for ProgressBar to disable user interaction?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-progressbar

I read this question about disabling user interaction while ProgressBar is visible: [How to disable user interaction while ProgressBar is visible in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918219/how-to-disable-user-interaction-while-progressbar-is-visible-in-android). But, isn't there a "cleaner" way to do it? Like in an xml attribute?

Comment: No, these's no way to disable all UI interaction while some element is visible.  That's a point where you actually need to do some programming.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:clickable="true"` in your `ProgressBar` xml