# Progress bar in stripes style?

Tags: android

I'm using ProgressBar in android for providing a progress bar. At the moment I have a common progress bar, like you can see in the attached picture at the top - just a blue bar. What techniques are possible to have a bar style with stripes like attaced in the picture? do I have to use an image with stripes as background for solving this? or do I have to provide a special "android:progressDrawable"? Thx for your hints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom progressbar with your own drawable. look at this topic: [Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)